# Indirectly accessing a string variable C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a Text Library that consist of various groups that have a number of messages.
i can access a specific message (and show the content in `Label.Text`) like this :

```cs
Label.Text = Globals.TextLibrary.Group1.Messages[0].Message;
```

i can define a string variable that will change dynamically to suit my needs :

```cs
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    string temp="Globals.TextLibrary." + this.InstanceName + ".Messages[" + i + "].Message";
                
    Label[i].Text= stringToName(temp); //need a way to make temp the variable name
}
```

Is there a way that i can use this 'temp' string as a variable name to retrieve the string from its location?

Variations of this I'm sure has been asked before, and I have searched through similar threads for a while now, without coming to a conclusion.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Frank

Comment: A relevant search term is "reflection"

Comment: Reflection would be the way, OR if it's in your control, then I would recommend to consider changing the type of `TextLibrary` to a `Dictionary<string, YourMessageClass[]>` instead of making it all so hardcoded. The datatype used should fit your needs, and when it's hardcoded it doesn't.

Comment: You can do this easily enough with reflection, though you should likely rethink the problem...

Comment: This is for manipulating an hmi device that has these built in text libraries. There probably is a better way of doing this, but this way is easy for me to maintain and easy to explain how others can maintain and update lists.

Comment: @TheGeneral, I've spent quite a while searching to no avail. If this is achievable with reflection, could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: If your goal is to access a string at the runtime location `Globals.TextLibrary." + this.InstanceName + ".Messages[" + i + "].Message` this can be done with reflection. However, after seeing marks answer, its likely I have misunderstood what you are trying to achieve. maybe you can clarify

Comment: Yes, that's what i need. `this.InstanceName` holds the correct Group name for a given situation. So in a situation where `Group1` is the instance, this would produce a desired result. `Label1.Text=Globals.TextLibrary.Group1.Messages[1].Message;`

Answer (score 0):

That's simply not a thing. You could create an API to provide a string, such as a `Func<string>` on an `interface` with a single `string` property-getter (and a concrete implementation), but that wouldn't help you here, as the thing you assign to `.Text` needs to be a `string`, not some proxy to a string. As an aside, there is such a thing as a `ref string`, but that also doesn't help you here for the same reasons, plus you can't really store a `ref` *anywhere* except in a local variable in a simple (non-rewritten) method.

Basically: you're going to need to know which `.Text` to update, and write code to do that periodically. You *could* perhaps use data-binding to something that has a number of `string` properties, and update *that* (assuming it also has notification events). This at least decouples the indirect source from the UI target, via a shared simple intermediary.

Comment: So the other comments i got about reflection is not relevant to my situation?

Comment: @Frank_ I don't see how reflection would help any here, no. Maybe I missed something in the question :shrug: